Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead
alidate items title on list page 
    @{expectedList} =  Create List    Iphone X    Samsung Note 8     Nokia Edge    Blackberry
    @{elements} =  Get WebElements         css:.card-title
    @{actualList} =  Create List
    FOR        ${element}   IN        @{elements}
               @{list} =  Create List        ${element.text}
                Log         ${element.text}
                Append To List        @{actualList}        @{list}

    END

Url:https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/shop
Unable to convert to list as it says Expected argument 1 to be a list or list-like, got string instead.

If you had pasted the original error and where it happened, we could have answered faster.
Here is you complete and reproducible test suite, with the corrections:

*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Validate items title on list page
    [Setup]    Open Browser    https://rahulshettyacademy.com/angularpractice/shop
    @{expectedList} =    Create List    Iphone X    Samsung Note 8    Nokia Edge    Blackberry
    @{elements} =    Get WebElements    css:.card-title
    @{actualList} =    Create List
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{elements}
            @{list} =    Create List    ${element.text[0]}    # This was where the error appeared because the value was: @{list} = [ iphone X ]
            Log    ${element.text}
            Append To List    ${actualList}    @{list}    # Here actualist must no be passed as expanded list
    END
    [Teardown]    Close All Browsers

This the execution messages log in RIDE:

[Edit] Note: This is actually a wrong solution because is only storing the first character of element.text. Using ${element.text} works!!
